# Custom Font not Available in Storyboard - Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, user-interface, fonts

I have an issue with Xcode: I can not find my custom font in the custom list when I am in a storyboard.

I have added my font correctly in my project :

- Target is selected
- Font added in `Info.plist`
- Font available in Bundle Ressource

My fonts:

[image: My fonts]

Plist:

[image: Plist]

Bunde Ressource:

[image: Bunde Ressource]

I tried to detect my font with some code :

```
for family: String in UIFont.familyNames {
   print("\(family)")
   for names: String in UIFont.fontNames(forFamilyName: family) {
      print("== \(names)")
   }
}
```

But I do not see my custom font in the list ...

Any idea, because I am stuck :(

Comment: I have already try to restart my Mac and Xcode, but it is not working. In fact, I already read all the other topic about issus with Font but I didn't find the solution to my problem.

Comment: Did you add the fonts to the target?

Answer (score 0):

According to this answer: all you need that just restart your Mac and Xcode. Pretty dummy but, looks like it working.

[Xcode custom fonts not showing up in Storyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32755428/xcode-custom-fonts-not-showing-up-in-storyboard)